# Does $\phi(n^k) = {n^{k-1}}\phi(n)$ always hold?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, totient-function

Let $\phi$ be Euler's totient function.

Here is my question:

> Does $\phi(n^k) = {n^{k-1}}\phi(n)$ always hold, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I came across this claim as **(A. Olofsson, pers. comm., Dec. 30, 2004)** from  the [MathWorld - Totient Function page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

Let $n,k$ be positive integers.

Let $p_1,...,p_s$ be the distinct prime factors of $n$.

Then we have the formula
$$\phi(n) = n(1 - 1/p_1)\cdots (1-1/p_s)\qquad\,$$
But $n$ and $n^k$ have the *same* distinct prime factors, hence
\begin{align*}
\phi(n^k) &= n^k(1 - 1/p_1)\cdots (1-1/p_s)\\[4pt]
&= n^{k-1}(n(1 - 1/p_1)\cdots (1-1/p_s))\\[4pt]
&= n^{k-1}\phi(n)
\end{align*}